# Windows Terminal - what is minifying my config on save?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, windows-terminal

I attempting to edit Windows Terminal's JSON config file:

[image]

When I save, the document is minified:

[image]

I only have two extensions (I have removed others and restarted vscode). How do I find out where the minification is occuring? How do I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Windows Terminal. **It's now fixed in the current Preview release.** Mike Griese from Microsoft [answered this via GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Terminal/issues/433#issuecomment-489802811):

> The profiles.json thing is a temporary thing. Unfortunately, Windows.Data.Json always writes out json as a single line, without the ability to pretty-print it, and we re-write the profiles.json to make sure that it stays up to date with the schema of the app. So currently, it'll keep re-writing it. But that's a huge pain point that we want to fix ASAP.